# Leasing Cashflow Excel

Tags: excel

I have to calculate a Leasing Model for technology equipment in Excel.
I have one row with continuous cash inflows of cash amounts of products sold.
Those products go into a leasing agreement with a premium leasing rate of 4% and will be leased for 36 months. The Excel sheet should provide me with cashflows adding up the lease payments for each monthly leasing rent in one cell.

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sold | 300 | 600 | 300 |
| Leasing Cashflow | =9.37 | =9.37+18.75 | =9.37+18.17+9.37 |

Comment: You should explain how would you manually calculate the leasing (how you obtain 9.37, 18.75 and so on)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I calculate "Sold" *(1+4%)^3/12. (3 because of the 36 months) and then divided by 12 because I want to have the monthly leasing fee)

Comment: Sorry but with that formula I don't get any of your single outputs. Please, edit your original question and type the formula and how you calculate with an example.